# select2 value not updated

Tags: select, vue.js, jquery-select2

I am using Vue 2.5.17 and Select2 4.0.6-rc.1.

I have a input field where I can select options. I want to pass the selected option to a store object.

This is the code in the component:

```
<select2 type="text" :options="bereiche" v-model="bereichInput" class="form-control">
```

(..)

```
computed: {
    bereichInput:{
        get () {
            return this.$store.state.bereichInputStore
        },
        set (value) {
            console.log("value="+value+"!");
            this.$store.commit('setBereichInput', value)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code in the store:

```
setBereichInput(state, bereichInput)
      {
        state.bereichInputStore = bereichInput;
        console.log("Test bereich"+state.bereichInputStore+"!!!!");
      }
```

When I test ist I got the following message in the console:

"Test bereich!!!!" 
Ergo nothing was passed!

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I don't work with stores yet, but select2 options are not handled directly by the DOM, so option changes don't trigger native browser "on" things *(best explantion ever)*. I hope I understood you right.

Comment: My solution was to make my own select2 component. Take a look at mine: https://gist.github.com/Fusseldieb/0e2bd6af4579a37cb1dabdd8866a80b5

Comment: I've just updated the gist (again). Should be ready for usage now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `v-model` with `vuex` when using that component. You'll need to handle the changing of the value yourself, and use `:value` for the binding capturing `@input` to determine when the value changes. Observe:

```
<select2 @input="updateBereiche"
         :options="bereiche"
         :value="bereichInput" 
         class="form-control">
```

Then you're going to add a new method called `updateBereiche`

```
methods: {
  updateBereiche(value) {
      this.$store.commit('setBereichInput', value)
  }
}
```

Remove your `setter`, it's not needed anymore.